# How to use UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute in .NET CF 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-cf-3.5

Wondering whether or not anyone has managed to use this in a .NET CF 3.5 program.

I'm getting the error: "The type or namespace name 'UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)", when attempting to debug.

This class is apparently present in InteropServices which I have included in the offending file ("using System.Runtime.InteropServices;").

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attribute is not available in .NET CF 3.5:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedfunctionpointerattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

> Platforms
>
> Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Media Center
>   Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP Starter
>   Edition, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server
>   2003, Windows Server 2000 SP4, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 98